# regex matching complete expression containing multiple, similar terms

Tags: python, regex

I have a string. For example:

```
s = "caption = #1081#1082#1083#1084', '#1087#1088 efiuefiu #23   3456"
```

I need to find all expressions consists of # and 4 digits, but I need to find expression `#1081#1082#1083#1084`, not `#1081`, `#1082`, `#1083` and `#1084` separately like this.

This doesn't work; it matches the individual expressions:

```
result = re.findall(r'#\d{4}', s)
```

Comment: `(#\d{4})+` -- https://regex101.com/r/sFP7L0/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look for *one or more occurrences* of `#` followed by 4 digits:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = "caption = #1081#1082#1083#1084', '#1087#1088 efiuefiu #23   3456"

In [3]: re.findall(r'(?:#\d{4})+', s)   
Out[3]: ['#1081#1082#1083#1084', '#1087#1088']
```

The `(?:...)` is a *non-capturing group* that helps to avoid matching a single occurrence of the desired pattern and "focus on a bigger picture" instead.

Comment: @GolovDanil: Compare http://ideone.com/5Aywyc with http://ideone.com/hl3J6J

Comment: @RobertHarvey
ahah, yes, I see, but why r'(#\d{4})+' doesn't find #1081 for example ??

Comment: Because it's not the last capturing group.

Comment: @alecxe, please explain the answer, code only answers cause such long discussions and "clarification" questions in the future.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah, good point, I hate code-only answers as well. Will improve it.